# Select,pipie and waitpd - how to wait for specyfic child?

Tags: c, linux, select, pipe, waitpid

He is the deal:
I have n `fork`, in fork I have `exec`, everything is connect with `pipe`.
My question:
If some child do `exit()` I want to `close` his `pipe` to be abble to read. - how to do this? Waitpid most likely...

Now I wait for all child like that:

```
for(i = 0; i< val; i++)
        {
                wait(&status);
                close(fd[i][1]);
        }
```

val - numbers of child.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you asking. If you want to close some connection made via pipe when child(ren) exits, then 1) ignore SIGPIPE (so that your parent/server doesn't exit -- default action for SIGPIPE is exit) 2) Look for EPIPE error number. 3) Close the file descriptor(s) that return `EPIPE`. Except for reaping purposes, you don't need to use wait() for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you fork, the parent receives the pid of the child.
You need to keep these pids in some data structure (a hash table or a linked list, perhaps).  You should also keep the pipe-fd associated with that pid.  So perhaps a datastructure like:

```
typedef struct pidsnpipes pidsnpipes;
struct pidsnpipes {
    pidsnpipes * next;       /* for linked list */
    pid_t        childpid;
    int          pipefd;     /* parents end of this pipe */
    int          status;     /* if you want to remember the child's exit status */
};

pidsnpipes * childprocs = NULL;
```

When `wait()` returns you get the pid of the child which exited (and optionally, its exit status).  Use that to lookup which pipe went with that process so you close the right pipe.